# What a Site Needs To Be Considered a WebApp?

Tags: web-development, web-applications

I've been looking at the Chrome Store and I started to think about developing some nice stuff to publish there, since I have a machine installed with Chromium and I see the WebApp market a lot better than the platform-specific one. But what a site really needs and how it should be designed to be considered a WebApp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a meaningful distinction. If you read Chrome Web Store [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/):

> Many installable web apps are hosted
>   apps—*normal websites* with a bit of
>   extra metadata. You can build and
>   deploy hosted apps exactly as you
>   would build and deploy any web app,
>   using any server-side or client-side
>   technologies you like. The only
>   difference is that you must provide a
>   small manifest file that describes the
>   app.

Emphasis mine.

Therefore even the Google docs sees no distiction between a normal site and a web app.

Answer (score 2):

All a website really **needs** to be considered the site of a web app is, well, an app. Of course there are many other things that **should** be on the site such as a Contact page and I believe that a company blog is always a nice touch. I recommend going with a minimalist layout for a web app as no body likes clutter.